# Android / Java: HttpURLConnection doesn't return headers of redirected file (e.g. on S3)

Tags: android, redirect, download, httpurlconnection

My code (reproduced below), connects to a url and downloads the file to disk on android.  All standard stuff. When I try using this code on a file on S3 accessed via a subdomain on our server mapped to a bucket (e.g. foo.example.com => bucket called foo.example.com), it often fails.  Turns out (using the handy curl command..

```
 "curl -v -L -X GET http://foo.example.com/f/a.txt")
```

.. that there's a redirect going on here.

The file download works ok, as HttpURLConnection will follow redirects by default, but the calls that require the header infomation (getContentLength, getHeaderFieldDate("Last-Modified", 0 ) etc) are returns the headers from the 307 redirect, and not the actual file thats downloaded.

Anyone know how to get around this?

Thanks

```
File local = null;
        try {


            Log.i(TAG, "Downloading file " + source);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(source).openConnection();
            fileSize = conn.getContentLength(); // ** THIS IS WRONG ON REDIRECTED FILES
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination, false), 8 * 1024); 
            conn.connect();

            stream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream(), 8 * 1024);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

            while (true) {
                int read = stream.read(buffer);

                if (read == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                // writing to buffer
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
                downloaded += read;

                publishProgress(downloaded, fileSize);

                if (isCancelled()) {
                    return "The user cancelled the download"; 
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = "Failed to download file " + source + ". " + e.getMessage();
            Log.e(TAG, msg );
            return msg;
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to close file " + destination);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (stream != null) {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to close file " + destination);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {

                long dateLong = conn.getHeaderFieldDate("Last-Modified", 0 ); // ** THIS IS WRONG ON REDIRECTED FILES

                Date d = new Date(dateLong);
                local.setLastModified(dateLong);
            }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have you tried to set redirects to false and try to manually capture the redirected URL and associated header fields with it?

For example something like this:

```
URL url = new URL(url); 
HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
ucon.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
URL secondURL = new URL(ucon.getHeaderField("Location")); 
URLConnection conn = secondURL.openConnection();
```

This example captures the redirected URL, but you could easily tweak this to try for any other header field. Does this help?

Comment: thanks. I guess it'd get a bit fiddly with multiple redirects but that may well help

Comment: I've run into other strange gotchas in the redirecting code for various Android components. Even on the same OS version, different devices would handle them differently. We switched to manual redirect as a result.

Comment: Ah, interesting.  I've been experimenting with using the apache HttpClient instead of HttpURLConnection, and it's been working for me (so far!).  Which android components have you had issues with?

Comment: I am using nearly *exactly* the same code, it gives the url of the redirect in Android 4.1 emulator, but the same code returns "null" in Android 2.2.2 device! Any ideas about why this fails?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [httpclient-android](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-android). You should get the right headers after redirection with this:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(YOUR_URL);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
response.getAllHeaders()
```

Note that android comes with an older version of httpclient, but it has the same problem as you reported. You [actually need](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html) to import "httpclient-android" for a newer version.

Note: The code snippet is for v4.3. For other versions, look for how to do it in regular apache HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've been playing a bit and this code, which uses the HttpClient library rather than HttpUrlConnection works fine. The headers it returns are those of the final redirect hop.
At least on the devices I've tested it on.

```
HttpClient client = null;
HttpGet get = null;
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
get = new HttpGet(source);
response = client.execute(get);

Header contentSize = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Length");
if (contentSize != null) {
 String value = contentSize.getValue();
 fileSize = Long.parseLong(value);
}
if (fileSize == -1) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read the content length for the file " + source);
}

Header lastModified = response.getFirstHeader("Last-Modified");
lastModifiedDate = null;
if (lastModified != null) {
    lastModifiedDate = DateUtils.parseDate(lastModified.getValue());
}
if (lastModifiedDate == null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to read the last modified date for the file " + source);
}

out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination, false), 8 * 1024);     // false means don't append
stream = new BufferedInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent(), 8 * 1024);

byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

int count = 0;
while (true) {
    int read = stream.read(buffer);

    if (read == -1) {
        break;
    }
    // writing to buffer
    out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    downloaded += read;

    publishProgress(downloaded, fileSize);

    if (isCancelled()) {
        Log.w(TAG, "User Cancelled");
        return; // NOTE that onPostExecute is not called here..
    }
}// end of while

publishProgress(downloaded, fileSize);

} catch (Exception e) {
String msg = "Failed to download file " + source + ". " + e.getMessage();
Log.e(TAG, msg );
return msg;
} finally {
if (out != null) {
    try {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to close file " + destination);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

if (stream != null) {
    try {
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to close file " + destination);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```